Handlebars is not defined" Error in NetSuite User Event Script
I’m fairly new to NetSuite, although I have done some maintenance work on existing SuiteScript code before. Currently, I’m working on a NetSuite User Event Script that uses Handlebars.js to generate a JSON payload from customer record data. However, I keep running into an error where the script logs "Handlebars is not defined". Despite trying different approaches to load and initialize Handlebars, the issue persists.
Environment:
NetSuite API Version: 2.0
Script Type: User Event Script
Script Trigger: After Submit on Customer record creation and edit
What I've Tried:
Loading Handlebars.js:
I uploaded the handlebars.min.js file to the SuiteScripts/Libraries folder in NetSuite.
I’m loading the library using the file.load() function and then trying to execute it using Function().
Attempt to Initialize Handlebars:
var handlebarsFile = file.load({ id: 'SuiteScripts/Libraries/handlebars.min.js' });
var handlebarsLib = handlebarsFile.getContents();
var Handlebars = Function(handlebarsLib + 'return Handlebars;')();

Error Handling:
Despite this, I’m consistently seeing the error "Handlebars is not defined" in the script execution logs.
Script Details:
Here's my script:
     /**
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType UserEventScript
     * @NModuleScope SameAccount
     */

    define(['N/record', 'N/log', 'N/file', 'N/https'], function(record, log, file, https) {

    function afterSubmit(context) {
        log.debug('Script Triggered', 'After Submit script triggered for customer record.');
        if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE && context.type !== context.UserEventType.EDIT) return;

        try {
            // Load the Handlebars.js library
            var handlebarsFile = file.load({
                id: 'SuiteScripts/Libraries/handlebars.min.js'
            });
            var handlebarsLib = handlebarsFile.getContents();

            // Execute the Handlebars library code in the current scope
            var Handlebars = Function(handlebarsLib + 'return Handlebars;')();

            log.debug('Handlebars Loaded', 'Successfully loaded Handlebars.');

            // Load the customer record
            var customer = record.load({
                type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                id: context.newRecord.id
            });

            log.debug('Customer Record Loaded', 'Customer ID: ' + customer.id);

            // Extract customer data
            var data = {
                email: customer.getValue('email') || '',
                firstname: customer.getValue('firstname') || '',
                lastname: customer.getValue('lastname') || '',
                username: customer.getValue('email') || '',
                phone: customer.getValue('phone') || '',
                role: customer.getText('pricelevel') || '',
                password: customer.getValue('custentity_pm_int_cust_pass') || '',
                billing: {},
                shipping: {}
            };

            // Extract address book data
            var addressCount = customer.getLineCount('addressbook');
            for (var i = 0; i < addressCount; i++) {
                var isBilling = customer.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'addressbook',
                    fieldId: 'defaultbilling',
                    line: i
                });
                var isShipping = customer.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'addressbook',
                    fieldId: 'defaultshipping',
                    line: i
                });

                var address = {
                    company: customer.getValue('companyname') || '',
                    firstname: customer.getValue('firstname') || '',
                    lastname: customer.getValue('lastname') || '',
                    addr1: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'addr1',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    addr2: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'addr2',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    city: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'city',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    state: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'state',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    zip: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'zip',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    country: customer.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'addressbook',
                        fieldId: 'country',
                        line: i
                    }) || '',
                    phone: customer.getValue('phone') || ''
                };

                if (isBilling) {
                    data.billing = address;
                    log.debug('Billing Address Found', JSON.stringify(address));
                }

                if (isShipping) {
                    data.shipping = address;
                    log.debug('Shipping Address Found', JSON.stringify(address));
                }
            }

            // Handlebars template as a string
            var templateSource =
                '{' +
                '"data":{' +
                '"email": "{{record.email}}",' +
                '"first_name": "{{record.firstname}}",' +
                '"last_name": "{{record.lastname}}",' +

                '{{#if record.pricelevel}}' +
                '"role": [' +
                '"{{wooCommerceRole record.pricelevel.name}}",' +
                '{{#if record.custentity_pm_int_ws_credit_hold}} "credit_hold", {{/if}}' +
                '{{#if_eq record.terms.internalid "4"}} "cod" {{else}} "terms" {{/if_eq}}' +
                '],' +
                '{{/if}}' +
                '{{#if record.custentity_pm_int_update_ws_pass}}' +
                '"password": "{{record.custentity_pm_int_cust_pass}}",' +
                '{{/if}}' +
                '"username": "{{record.email}}",' +
                '"phone": "{{record.phone}}"' +
                '{{#if (gt record.addressbook.length 0)}}' +
                '{{#each record.addressbook}}' +
                '{{#if defaultbilling}}' +
                ',"billing": {' +
                '"company": "{{../record.companyname}}",' +
                '"first_name": "{{../record.firstname}}",' +
                '"last_name": "{{../record.lastname}}",' +
                '"address_1": "{{addr1}}",' +
                '"address_2": "{{addr2}}",' +
                '"city": "{{city}}",' +
                '"state": "{{state}}",' +
                '"postcode": "{{zip}}",' +
                '"country": "{{country}}",' +
                '"phone": "{{../record.phone}}"' +
                '}' +
                '{{/if}}' +
                '{{/each}}' +
                '{{#each record.addressbook}}' +
                '{{#if defaultshipping}}' +
                ',"shipping": {' +
                '"company": "{{../record.companyname}}",' +
                '"first_name": "{{../record.firstname}}",' +
                '"last_name": "{{../record.lastname}}",' +
                '"address_1": "{{addr1}}",' +
                '"address_2": "{{addr2}}",' +
                '"city": "{{city}}",' +
                '"state": "{{state}}",' +
                '"postcode": "{{zip}}",' +
                '"country": "{{country}}",' +
                '"phone": "{{../record.phone}}"' +
                '}' +
                '{{/if}}' +
                '{{/each}}' +
                '{{/if}}' +
                '}' +
                '}';

            // Compile the Handlebars template with the data
            var hbTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
            var jsonData = hbTemplate({
                record: data
            });

            log.debug('Generated JSON', jsonData);

            // Send the JSON to the middleware endpoint
            var response = https.post({
                url: 'https://middleware.exampleserver.io/customer-sync',
                body: jsonData,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

            log.debug('Response from API', response.body);

        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Error in afterSubmit', e.message);
        }
    }

    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
});

Original Handlebars Template:
Here's the original Handlebars template I'm trying to work with:
{
"data": {
    "email": "{{record.email}}",
    "first_name": "{{record.firstname}}",
    "last_name": "{{record.lastname}}",

    {
        {
            #if record.pricelevel
        }
    }
    "role": [
            "{{wooCommerceRole record.pricelevel.name}}",
            {
                {
                    #if record.custentity_pm_int_ws_credit_hold
                }
            }
            "credit_hold",
            {
                {
                    /if}} {
                        {
                            #if_eq record.terms.internalid "4"
                        }
                    }
                    "cod" {
                        {
                            else
                        }
                    }
                    "terms" {
                        {
                            /if_eq}}
                        ], {
                            {
                                /if}} {
                                    {
                                        #if record.custentity_pm_int_update_ws_pass
                                    }
                                }
                                "password": "{{record.custentity_pm_int_cust_pass}}", {
                                    {
                                        /if}}
                                        "username": "{{record.email}}",
                                        "phone": "{{record.phone}}" {
                                            {
                                                #ifgreaterthan record.addressbook.length 0
                                            }
                                        } {
                                            {
                                                #each record.addressbook
                                            }
                                        } {
                                            {
                                                #if defaultbilling
                                            }
                                        }, "billing": {
                                            "company": "{{{../record.companyname}}}",
                                            "first_name": "{{../record.firstname}}",
                                            "last_name": "{{../record.lastname}}",
                                            "address_1": "{{addressbookaddress.addr1}}",
                                            "address_2": "{{addressbookaddress.addr2}}",
                                            "city": "{{addressbookaddress.city}}",
                                            "state": "{{addressbookaddress.state}}",
                                            "postcode": " {{addressbookaddress.zip}}",
                                            "country": "{{addressbookaddress.country.internalid}}",
                                            "phone": " {{{../record.phone}}}"
                                        }

                                        {
                                            {
                                                /if}} {
                                                    {
                                                        /each}}

                                                        {
                                                            {
                                                                #each record.addressbook
                                                            }
                                                        } {
                                                            {
                                                                #if defaultshipping
                                                            }
                                                        }, "shipping": {
                                                            "first_name": "{{../record.firstname}}",
                                                            "last_name": "{{../record.lastname}}",
                                                            "company": "{{{../record.companyname}}}",
                                                            "address_1": "{{addressbookaddress.addr1}}",
                                                            "address_2": "{{addressbookaddress.addr2}}",
                                                            "city": "{{addressbookaddress.city}}",
                                                            "state": "{{addressbookaddress.state}}",
                                                            "postcode": " {{addressbookaddress.zip}}",
                                                            "country": "{{addressbookaddress.country.internalid}}",
                                                            "phone": " {{{../record.phone}}}"
                                                        } {
                                                            {
                                                                /if}} {
                                                                    {
                                                                        /each}} {
                                                                            {
                                                                                /ifgreaterthan}}
                                                                            }
                                                                        }

What I Need Help With:
Correct Method for Loading Handlebars.js: Is there a more reliable way to load and initialize Handlebars in a NetSuite SuiteScript environment?
Alternatives: If Handlebars is not viable in SuiteScript, what alternatives would you suggest for dynamically generating JSON from a template?
Maybe I’m going about this the wrong way, so I’d really appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can offer.

@Brian Duffy's answer is the way to go if you need handlebars. Using Handlebars to create JSON is a bit odd though. Just create the structure yourself using code. IMO this will be way cleaner and easier to maintain.

I would agree to the above comment that doing it yourself using code is the best and easy option use template literals if ES6 compatible. alternatively use lodash to take care of the templating

You'll need to define your handlebars library ...'N/https','./Libraries/handlbars.min']... and then set variable for it in function ...https, Handlebars) {...
/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4704097697.html
